# How do I make "intersection of 2 lists" predicate?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to make intersection of 2 lists (i.e. list C contains those and only those elements, that are in A and B), yet as I understand, I get disjunction of 2 lists + any amount of any elements in C.

Intended to work like:

- if X is in C, then it must be both in A and in B. (I believe X should iterate ALL members of C !?)
- predicate: `d(A,B,C) :- (member(X,D)->member(X,A),member(X,B)).`

Can you tell: Are my sentence and predicate not equal or did I make another error?

example:

```
?- [user].

|: d(A,B,C) :- (member(X,D)->(member(X,A),member(X,B))).
|: % user://1 compiled 0.01 sec, 612 bytes
true.

?- d([a,b],[b,c],C)
|    .
C = [b|_G21] .

?- d([a,b],[b,c],[b]).
true .
```

Comment: This is called intersection not disjunction

Comment: "Disjunction" refers to "logical OR" or (more loosely) "union". "Conjunction" would be "logical AND" or (more loosely) "intersection".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `O(NlogN)` solution with duplicates removed:

```
% untested
intersection(A, B, O) :-
    sort(A, AS),
    sort(B, BS),
    intersection1(AS, BS, O).

intersection1(A, B, O) :-
    (    A = [AH|AT],
         B = [BH|BT]
    ->   (    AH == BH
         ->   O = [AH|OT],
              intersection1(AT, BT, OT)
         ;    (    AH @< BH
              ->   intersection1(AT, B, O)
              ;    intersection1(A, BT, O) ) )
     ;   O = [] ).
```

Comment: some else branch is missing

Answer (score 1):

I like the solution proposed by @salva, though I'd do a more straightforward sort-and-merge, chucking anything that doesn't match instead:

```
intersect( As , Bs , Cs ) :-
  sort( As , SortedAs ) ,
  sort( Bs , SortedBs ) ,
  merge( SortedAs , SortedBs , Cs )
  .

merge( []     , []     , [] ).
merge( []     , [_|_]  , [] ).
merge( [_|_]  , []     , [] ).
merge( [C|As] , [C|Bs] , [C|Cs] ) :-          merge(    As ,     Bs  , Cs ) .
merge( [A|As] , [B|Bs] , Cs     ) :- A @< B , merge(    As  , [B|Bs] , Cs ) .
merge( [A|As] , [B|Bs] , Cs     ) :- A @> B , merge( [A|As] ,    Bs  , Cs ) .
```

Comment: The problem with that implementation is that, for most (all?) Prolog implementations, it leaves lots of choice-points behind.

Answer (score 0):

your predicate d/3 should be reformulated in *constructive* terms, since Prolog it's 'a tuple at once' relational language:

```
d(X,Y,Z) :- findall(E, (member(E,X), memberchk(E,Y)), Z).
```

that yields

```
?- d([a,b],[b,c],C).
C = [b].
```

[memberchk](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=memberchk/2)/2 it's the deterministic version of [member](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=member/2)/2, used here to enumerate all X' elements. You could understand better the difference if you replace memberchk with member and try to call d/3 with lists containing duplicates.

[findall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3)/3 it's the simpler 'all solutions' list constructor.